# How to find the limit of $f(x+5) - f(x-8)$, given that $\lim _{x \to \infty} f'(x)= 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

let $f,g$ be two differentiable functions that are defined on $\mathbb R$. its given that $g'$ is a bounded function and also given that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x)= 0$:

- show that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x+5) - f(x-8) = 0$
- $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} g(f(x)) - g(f([x]))=0$

I don't have a direction to solve these questions, any help?

Comment: For the first bullet, we are merely shifting the function $f\left(x\right)$ left or right, and thus at arbitrarily large values would be subtracting it from itself, resulting in 0.

Comment: thanks for the intuition. but do u have a suggestion for how to write this formally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* By the Mean Value Theorem, for every $x$,

$$\frac{f(x+5) - f(x-8)}{(x+5) - (x-8)} = \frac{f(x+5) - f(x-8)}{13} = f'(c)$$
for some $c \in [x-8,x+5]$.

You also know that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $M$ such that $c > M \ \Rightarrow |f'(c)| < \epsilon$. Hence ...

Comment: And here I was thinking that $f$ with $f(x)=\sin\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$ was going to be a counterexample. Amazing that $\lim \limits_{x\to+\infty}\left(\sin(\sqrt{x+5})-\sin(\sqrt{x-8})\right)$ exists

Comment: I know what you mean